# How can I change Camera settings after start(vid)?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-figure

I've a problem with the Matlab Acquisition Toolbox.
Actually I set the camera settings (like Exposure, Focus, Brightness,...) and then, for different reasons I do start(vid).

But...when I do start(vid) I completely lose my camera settings. How can I solve this problem?